# SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable, syntax-error

I'm trying to do an ajax request, code below, with mix datatable.js. But i don't find the glue.

```
let php_datas = '<?php echo $_path."|".json_encode($LNG). "|".json_encode($array_uzers)."|".$month ."|".$year."|".$membre."|".$user ."|".$debut_ts."|".$fin_ts."|".$get_payments ."|".json_encode($links_displayed); ?>';
let num_links = '<?php echo ($num_links + $nb_display_links);  ?>';
let nb_display_links = '<?php echo ($nb_links + 500); ?>';
console.log(php_datas);
setTimeout(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'lib/ajx_List_link.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'php_datas='+php_datas+'num_links='+num_links+'nb_links='+nb_display_links,

        success: function (jsondatas) {

            let links_displayed = jQuery.parseJSON(jsondatas);

            for(let i = 0; i < links_displayed.length ;i++){

                let table = $('#datatable-example').DataTable();

                        //links_displayed[i]["currency"]

                        let Row = "<tr id=''><td>"links_displayed[i]["checkbox"]"</td></tr>";


                table.row.add(Row).draw(  );
                }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert ('elle est où ma data ?');
        }

    });

}, 5000);
```

thanks a lot

Comment: But, what is your question?

Comment: And where's the PHP?

Comment: @JonStirling first two lines...some php

Comment: Which line has the error?  Is the error coming from PHP or JavaScript?  Don't just dump a bunch of code here, be specific.

Comment: here's one error: `let Row = "<tr id=''><td>"links_displayed` - missing a `+`

Comment: Is this in a .js file? Or in .php file?

Comment: what you do for `php_datas` is.... well, strange. and error-prone.

Comment: also this `data: 'php_datas='+php_datas+'num_links=...` will not work

Answer (score 2):

You forget the + for concatenation in your JS no ?

```
let Row = "<tr id=''><td>" + links_displayed[i]["checkbox"] + "</td></tr>";
```

Edit :

Andchange your data line in your ajax like this :

```
data: 'php_datas='+php_datas+'&num_links='+num_links+'&nb_links='+nb_display_links,
```

Comment: Also, for `'php_datas='+php_datas+'num_links`... should be `'php_datas='+php_datas+'&num_links`...

Comment: Yeah, same thing for ´&nb_links´

Comment: What I meant is edit your answer and add this information.